# How to stop images from showing the "blank document" icon while they are loading?

Tags: html, image, loading

I have a bunch of server-side generated images with the following HTML tags:

```
<img width="75" height="75" src="/MyController/MyAction/_ac=4d04359f-0d66-45d3-881c-b198e95a8215" data-idx="1">
```

The problem is that the images show the default "blank document" (or "missing image") icon and a border while they are loading. It looks like this:

[image: http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2044/2538847186_0c3ca2f9b1.jpg]

After images are loaded, the icon of course disappears, and the broder gets set to the one I specified in my CSS.

I don't want to create fancy preloaders and what not, but I would like to make this "blank document" icon and the default border to go away. Although the user sees it for a less than a second, still that's not good because it creates an impression that something is wrong with my images.

How do I make that icon not to show up while images are being loaded?

One idea was to set background for images, but I cannot do that because images have transparent areas, and then some parts of the background will be visible after the image has been loaded.

**UPDATE WITH A WORKAROUND**

I noticed that if I do not specify width and height, the default missing icon and border is not shown while the image is loading. As a workaround I did the following:

```
<div class="imgholder"><img src="/MyController/MyAction/_ac=4d04359f-0d66-45d3-881c-b198e95a8215" data-idx="1"></div>
```

and style the image holder as follows:

```
.imgholder {
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 2px;
            width: 75px; /* fixed dimensions - should match image sizes to avoid cropping */
            height: 75px;
            overflow: hidden; /* never show scrollbar */
            float: left;
        }
```

Still, it would be great to have some way to style the loading image itself and get rid of that image holder `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the broken icon show on every browser? Either way, have you tried this jquery plugin: [Imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) ? It may help in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use alternate text property.

One question how you are loading images? Loading using async calls or loading these images while page loads?

Comment: The missing icon shows up in both cases, no matter if I load them async or not. alt property does not remove the "missing" icon during image loading.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("img").on({load:function(){},
                  error:function(){
                    $(this).attr("src","blank.png")
                    });
```

Comment: In my case error handler is not triggered because the image is loaded just fine at the end. It just takes some time to load it, and during loading,the "missing" icon is visible. At least, in Mozilla Firefox.